# How can I add FTP commands to an alias?

Tags: ftp, alias

I'm starting to get familiar with the shell and command line, I just want to know how I can get backups from some specific folders and send them to my server using just one command.

I set `.netrc` (with my user/password) for my ftp command and now it works. I just need to add " put my_file " in my alias so it runs after ftp connects.

```
alias save='tar -czvf backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz /home/user/.bash*'
alias ftpme='ftp 10.1.1.172'
```

I need to add 'put my_file' in the code above so both commands run when I type `ftpme`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your ftp `put` command(s), followed by a `quit` command, in a file (say `/path/to/ftpcommands`) and do:

```
ftp 10.1.1.172 < /path/to/ftpcommands
```

In the ftpcommands file, you can also put your FTP user name and password (as `user [username] [password]`), if you like, bypassing the `.netrc` file.

You may also want to redirect the output of the ftp command to a log file, in case anything goes wrong. That would be something like

```
ftp 10.1.1.172 < /path/to/ftpcommands > /path/to/ftp.log 2>&1
```

This will redirect all messages from the ftp command to the log file ftp.log.